# Why did my Inquisitor increase the foreign religion?

Tags: civilization-6

I had a religion, somewhat like taoism. A bunch of apostles came to my main city and converted more than half of my people. Afterwards, I went with an Inquisitor to repel them, but my Inquisitor only increased the foreign religion. Is this a bug or is meant to be like that?

Comment: not quite the same - but similar: I had an apostle with the eradicate other religions promotion and used him - the religious lens showed my religion had the majority (and no other religions were present), but the city still had the other religion's logo and was coloured differently in the religion lens...

Comment: If I tagged the incorrect game (I'm basing this on the answer), then feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 13):

Any religious units you make will follow the majority religion of that city.  So if you purchased the Inquisitor after that city was converted, then the Inquisitor would be of the foreign religion and would remove your religion when used. So yes, it's meant to be like that.

As for regaining your religion, you could purchase an Inquisitor in another city that is still Taoist.  If you do not have any Taoist cities left, I don't know of a way to regain your religion.  Sounds like a good time to pivot to another victory type!

Comment: ok, yes it was civ 6, and i think that clears it up. thanks.

Comment: Could be dated, but in Civ5 a holy city was almost impossible to keep as anything but its native religion and Great Prophets are always your religion. TL;DR - you should be able to get your religion back even if it's been completely wiped.